# Finding pairs of complementary numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge

This is the "[Pairs with Positive Negative values](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/pairs-with-positive-negative-values/0)" problem from geeksforgeeks.org.

> Given an array of distinct integers, print all the pairs having positive value and negative value of a number that exists in the array.
>
> **NOTE**: If there is no such pair in the array , print **"0"**.
>
> **Input:**
>   The first line consists of an integer **T** i.e number of test cases. The first line of each test case consists of an integer **n**. The next line of each test case consists of **n** spaced integers.
>
> **Output:**
>   Print all the required pairs in the increasing order of their absolute numbers.

Here is my code:

```
def findPairs(l):
    listLen=len(l)
    nums=set()
    for i in range(listLen):
        if (-1*l[i]) in l[i+1:]:
            nums.add(abs(l[i]))
            continue 
    nums=sorted(nums)
    #print (nums)
    pairs=[]
    for num in nums:
        pairs.extend([-1*num,num])

    return pairs    


T=int(input())
pair=[]
for i in range(T):
    input()
    pair=findPairs(list(map(int,input().split())))
    if len(pair):
        print(" ".join(str(x) for x in pair))
    else:
        print("0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely incorporated the response to your previous questions, such as:

- Extract code into functions.
- Always indent with 4 spaces.
- Process input immediately instead of storing all input data and results in lists.

There is still too little (horizontal) whitespace, I suggest to check
your code against the [PEP8 coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
for example at [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com/checkresult).

Also function and variable names should be `snake_case` according to PEP8.

*More suggestions:*

- Variable names: `T` is too short and non-descriptive, `num_tests` 
  would be better. `pair` is better named `pairs`.
- There is no need to pre-assign `pair=[]`.
- The value of the iterator variable `i` in the main loop is not needed,
  a common convention is use `_` instead:

  ```
  for _ in range(T):
  ```
- Negation as in `-1*l[i]` can be simplified to `-l[i]`
- When printing the result list

  ```
  print(" ".join(str(x) for x in pair))
  ```

  you can use `map` instead, as you already do when reading the input:

  ```
  print(" ".join(map(str, pair)))
  ```

*Improving the performance:*

Your algorithm has two nested loops traversing through the list, i.e. the
time complexity is \$ O(n^2) \$ as a function of the list length.

This can be improved by sorting the list first. One option would be to sort
the numbers in increasing order, e.g.

```
-3 -1 1 2 3 6
```

for the first test case, and then traverse the list from both ends to find
pairs. The time complexity is \$ O(n \log n) \$ for the sorting, and 
 \$ O(n) \$ for the traversal, so this would be faster for large input.

Another option is to sort the number in increasing absolute value, e.g.

```
 -3 3 -1 1 2 6
```

Again a linear sweep of the sorted list is now sufficient to find matching pairs,
which are now *consecutive* entries.

Here is a possible implementation of the second approach:

```
def find_pairs(numbers):
    numbers.sort(key=lambda x: x + 0.5 if x >= 0 else -x)
    pairs = []
    for pair in [(x, y) for x, y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]) if x == -y]:
        pairs.extend(pair)
    return pairs
```

using

- `sort()` with a custom key. This relies on the given fact that the numbers are
  distinct integers.
- `zip` and list comprehension to enumerate pairs of consecutive list entries.